# How to load 16 bits images with UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I am going to optimize the memory usage of my app.
My app has many UIs with graphics which consume much of the device memory.

I tried to use 16 bits images instead of those of 32 bits.
The memory consumption of my OpenGL textures is reduced.
However, I found that the images held by UIImage consume the same amount of memory as 32 bits images.

Is that UIImage use 8bits per pixel to store the images no matter the pixel format is 16 or 32 bits?
Or wt can I do to reduce the memory consumption by 16 bits images??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use "pngcrush" available in mac.But if you do that,you can only view that images in iphone or ios.not in mac or any other systems.its optimization is like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the cgdata provider

```
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"some_file.png"]);
```

and then use the

```
CGImageRef CGImageCreate (
   size_t width,
   size_t height,
   size_t bitsPerComponent,
   size_t bitsPerPixel,
   size_t bytesPerRow,
   CGColorSpaceRef colorspace,
   CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo,
   CGDataProviderRef provider,
   const CGFloat decode[],
   bool shouldInterpolate,
   CGColorRenderingIntent intent
);
```

function, setting all the appropriate values for dimensions, bits per pixel and using the data provider created in the first step.

Then get UIImage out of CGImageRefs by [UIImage imageWithCGImage:] method.

Comment: thanks. i made a UIImage from ur help and init a UIImageView with it, and added it to my mainview. but i got a crash with the autorelease pool when the system rendering the view. The app crashed at the line "decode_data" (a internal function call of CAlayer render), i passed a NULL to the decode[] parameter for CGImageCreate, that's wt the documentation suggested. do u hv any idea wt caused the crash?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Core Graphics, sorry... I'd double check the values you supply for structs like colorspace of bitmapinfo, check if you are not releasing them prematurely.

Comment: i guess that 16 bits is not supported with some searching and trying. i cant work it out with ur answer(but of cox it does provided very useful information for me), so i cant mark it correct. Thanks so much.

Comment: I have the same optimize, but fail to reduce memory usage. Did you make it work?